# why mocked object function throws nulls instead of mocked data when using RobolectricTestRunner?

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, robolectric

i have this test class running with `MockitoJUnitRunner` before and then i added `RoboLectric`, now i use `RobolectricTestRunner`

So the first thing it tryed is running my old tests but just changing the runner and the test now always fail. I do not really understand what is happening here, i am just trying to make my old test work with `RobolectricTestRunner` without stop using `Mockito`.

**My Code before changing to RoboLectric (TEST PASS SUCCESSFULLY)**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class LauncherViewModelTest {

    companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val schedulers = RxImmediateeSchedulerRule()
    }

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockContext: MyApplication

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockedDatabase: MyDatabase

    @Mock
    private lateinit var session: Session

    // 
    @Mock
    lateinit var mockedDatabaseRxWrapper: DatabaseRxWrapper

    /** Evaluated class **/

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var launcherViewModel: LauncherViewModel

    @Test
    fun checkIfHasSessionSuccess() {

        val sessionFlowable: Flowable<Session> = Flowable.fromCallable { session }

        FieldSetter.setField(launcherViewModel,
                launcherViewModel.javaClass.getDeclaredField("databaseRxWrapper"), mockedDatabaseRxWrapper)

        doReturn(sessionFlowable).`when`(mockedDatabaseRxWrapper).getSession()

        launcherViewModel.checkIfHasSession()

        //$hasSession is a mutable live data
        Assert.assertEquals(true, launcherViewModel.hasSession.value)
    }
}
```

**My Code after changing to RoboLectric :** (DatabaseRxWrapper.getSession() returns always null even when i use Mockito.doReturn().when())

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class LauncherViewModelTest {

    companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val schedulers = RxImmediateeSchedulerRule()
    }

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockContext: MyApplication

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockedDatabase: MyDatabase

    @Mock
    private lateinit var session: Session

    // 
    @Mock
    lateinit var mockedDatabaseRxWrapper: DatabaseRxWrapper

    /** Evaluated class **/

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var launcherViewModel: LauncherViewModel

    @Test
    fun checkIfHasSessionSuccess() {

        val sessionFlowable: Flowable<Session> = Flowable.fromCallable { session }

        FieldSetter.setField(launcherViewModel,
                launcherViewModel.javaClass.getDeclaredField("databaseRxWrapper"), mockedDatabaseRxWrapper)

        doReturn(sessionFlowable).`when`(mockedDatabaseRxWrapper).getSession()

        launcherViewModel.checkIfHasSession()

        //$hasSession is a mutable live data
        Assert.assertEquals(true, launcherViewModel.hasSession.value)
    }
}
```

**Class under Test**

```
class LauncherViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

        @Inject
        lateinit var databaseRxWrapper: DatabaseRxWrapper

        val hasSession: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

        val application by lazy { getApplication<MyApplication>() }

        init {
            application.getAppComponent()?.inject(this)
        }

        fun saveLocation(location: Location) = sharedPreferenceManager.saveLocation(location)

        fun checkIfHasSession() {
            databaseRxWrapper.getSession()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    hasSession.postValue(true)
                }, {
                    hasSession.postValue(false)
                })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you don't need the rule for rewriting the configuration of RX if you are running with Robolectric

So the code worked after deleting this classrule:

```
companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val schedulers = RxImmediateeSchedulerRule()
    }
```